# Detect Java in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, java, malware

A vBulletin site I manage has been infected by some malware, it tries to run a java applet. Is there a way I can get chrome to show me where in the source the applet is coming from so I can remove it?

Comment: Have you tried crt + shift + j?

Comment: @soandos java != javascript

Comment: Have you looked for `embed type="application/x-java-applet"`?